# Native android application using webrtc

Tags: android, webrtc

I am working on webrtc -video calling application in android. The app not working when using appr.tc as room-server url.When I try to establish the connection between the browser and the app I always receive the following error -

```
Request TURN from: https://networktraversal.googleapis.com/v1alpha/iceconfig?key=AIzaSyAJdh2HkajseEIltlZ3SIXO02Tze9sO3NY
E/WSRTCClient: Room IO error: java.io.IOException: Non-200 response when requesting TURN server from https://networktraversal.googleapis.com/v1alpha/iceconfig?key=AIzaSyAJdh2HkajseEIltlZ3SIXO02Tze9sO3NY : HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Please tell me if you have any suggestions.Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You need to use POST request to fetch the API,it's 404 because you're using GET

Comment: I am not getting 404 error and I am using post request.@ Druid Virtual

Comment: Or because POST without adding header
< "Referer" :" h t t p s://a p p r.t c/ "> ?

Comment: I was need to update ice server provider response format in android app and error get resolved.Thank you for your response :)@Druid Virtual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your own TURN servers. Google is not going to do that for you.

Comment: I was asking about this -  https://appr.tc/ and i run my application with help of this.@Philipp Hancke